# Navigation styling help

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with my navigation menu, I have some `li` that are floated left of each other, and each li has a back ground image set to the right to give a seperation effect, within the `li` I have a `a` that is text aligned center.

On hover I have a `bottom-border` but I need said board to span the full width of the `li` not the `a` is this possible?

Here is a fiddle of my current attempt,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sRL7U/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS should do the trick:

```
header nav a { width:100%; }
```